# How to verify that secure https pages load without any browser warnings?

Tags: web-applications, ssl, https

Several times I discovered that site visitors get scared off by browser warning messages in https pages due to resources being loaded insecurely by the page. This is especially disastrous when it kills conversion rates in signup or payment pages since there's no noticeable backend error nor a client-side javascript error that can be caught...

There are the relatively simple problems of an image/css/js file being linked with an absolute url that's in http protocol. However, I also encountered such https warnings that are due to a social plugin like plusone which, inside its iframe (which has a https src), may load insecure resources occasionally.

Therefore, I'm wondering if there's any simple and elegant way to automate checking secure pages that can verify if they would load in an actual browser without any https warning.

Comment: You could do a search through your web source for `http://` and replace all absolute links with relative links, but I don't think there'd be a way to test for iframe'd source.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is setting up https locally (using a self-signed certificate), and just surf to the site in different browsers.

Another way is to use a headless browser, such as PhantomJS, fetch the page, and iterate over all links, iframes, and child documents, and change the source.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the impact of browser warnings - I've seen dramatic drop-offs in conversion rates when bugs cause SSL pages to generate browser warnings (up to 90% on an ecommerce site that had an expired certificate...).

It all depends on your development process, but what I've set up in the past was:
 - a private test environment, hosted on a subdomain of the live site
 - a "wildcard" SSL certificate for all of the top level domain, deployed both to live and the test environment
 - automatic, regular deployments of "work in progress" code to the test environment
 - automatic, scripted tests to follow key user journeys through site (using Selenium in our case)
 - email notification in case of browser warnings for any of the steps in the key user journeys

This process is commonly known as "Continuous Integration", and whilst it takes some effort to set up, it prevents the "whoops, we deployed an update and it's broken the site, and we only found out because nobody's buying our widgets online any more..." syndrome.